# [make Error]Installing OpenCV 3 on Ubuntu16.04 Python

Tags: python, c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to install openCV 3.1.0 on Ubuntu16.04 with python. I get the following error after the below. I have recently updated to ubuntu16.04 from ubuntu14.04. on ubuntu 14.04, I had opencv 2.4.9.1 and that is still working on my ubuntu16.04.

the default python is 2.7.12

Can somebody tell me where I'm going wrong?
Any clues would be appreciated.
※I'm a newbie

I have referred the below websites:

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/
http://embedonix.com/articles/image-processing/installing-opencv-3-1-0-on-ubuntu/#comment-697

---

### Command

`snoopy@snoopy-HP-ProBook-6560b:~/opencv-3.1.0/build$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON /home/snoopy/opencv-3.1.0/

snoopy@snoopy-HP-ProBook-6560b:~/opencv-3.1.0/build$ make`

---

### Error

`[  6%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/dnn.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/opencl_kernels_dnn.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so', needed by 'lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6741: recipe for target 'modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: I meet the same problem, have you solve it?

Comment: Hi @Philokey,   sorry for the late reply, my mail box was overloaded.  I got help from my colleague and this problem has resolved now and its working fine.  Below are some notes I took then.  Hope this helps.  1. make clean  2. rm -rf CmakeFiles/  3. cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..  4. make -j7  5. sudo make install  6. pkg-config --modversion opencv (to check version)       [For some reason the input of this comment is not showing as expected(line breaks and indent) *the above indicates a numbered list of six items*]

Comment: Thank you. I will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

I ran cmake with this option: -D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF    and it solved my problem.
You can also build ffmpeg lib from source code to solve this.

See here https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/3rdparty/ffmpeg

Comment: thanks! I'm sure someone will find this very helpful.